# mysql group concat

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1111

how can I group concat? here is my query

```
select t.date, group_concat(count(*)) from table1 t
group by t.date
```

but it returns error "Invalid use of group function"

If I use query like this

```
select t.date, count(*) from table1 t
group by t.date
```

then it returns following output but I want to group_concat this output

```
2011-01-01  100
2011-01-02  97
2011-01-03  105
```

Comment: Well, what do you want to do? There's no reason to use GROUP_CONCAT on the resultset, that's the role of the application language.

Comment: So what should your final result look like?

Comment: @Martin I want output like this 100,97,105

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`cnt` ORDER BY `date`) 
FROM (
    SELECT t.`date`, COUNT(*) AS `cnt`
    FROM `table1` t
    GROUP BY t.`date`
) d
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to count the number of date rows group by date?

I use this statement to count number of invoice items per date in a specific month.

```
SELECT date(i.Date), count(*) cnt
FROM invoice i
WHERE MONTH(i.Date) = 3
GROUP BY date(i.Date)
```

This will group all dates that are the same. Is this what you meant?

I use GROUP_CONCAT for subqueries returning more than one row.

*** EDIT ***
OUPS, saw that my suggestion was the same as your already tried. Then I don't understand what you are looking for. Can you please show an example of desired result?

Comment: I want output like this
Query: select group_concat(count(*)) from table group by date
Output: 100,97,105

Comment: Hello, Max could you take a look on my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75136136/replace-with-array-from-a-select-group-concat

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this :

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(n) groupN
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) n
      FROM table1
      GROUP BY date) tmp
```

But that's not the role of the RDBMS! Cosmetic is the role of your application language (PHP, Python, Ruby, whatever), your query should only select your data, period. Therefore, GROUP_CONCAT is not the solution in this case.

Comment: Wouldn't that equally apply to all questions using `GROUP_CONCAT`?

Comment: @Martin: Most of the time, yes, actually. I'm not saying it's evil, and it's most likely the only solution with MySQL when you want to do something like this, but it's not in ANSI SQL and there are other ways to do a GROUP_CONCAT-like operation with ANSI SQL (and it's more complicated, I agree).

Comment: Hello, Vincent could you take a look on my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75136136/replace-with-array-from-a-select-group-concat